# Laravel Inactivity time setting

Tags: laravel, timeout, logout

When user logged-in and remains inactive, How many seconds after that system logouts the user automatically? How to change this setting?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Assuming you are using the session driver to handle your authentication, you can change the time period for an idle session to expire in the `/app/config/session.php` file.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Comment: So after 120 s , to all the Auth::user will be auto logged out ? Is that correct ?

Comment: It's **minutes**. So after 120 minutes the user will be logged out.

Comment: Ohh nice. Thanks for clarify. So I assume at the 119.999 minutes the program will automatically called the **Auth::logout();** function at some point. Is that right ? Do you know where that in Laravel ? The reason why I am asking this, is because I want to set some value into my database before the log-out function. I hope to hear back from you. :)

Comment: @iori were you ever able to figure this out? I also want to run a command before auto logout

Comment: The program will not automatically log the user out. 

Every time the user access a page on the site it will do a check to see if the time between their last visit is > x minutes . If it is, then the application logs them out, but the user needs to visit the site to trigger this.

Comment: @NightMICU If you want to trigger some code every time a user is logged out, you could use an [event subscriber](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events#event-subscribers) for the `auth.logout` event.

Comment: @Jeemusu this also make the csrf token expire in the same time, is there a way to only expire the user's session?

Comment: The location of this file has changed to `/config/session.php`