# How to automatically logout all users from all devices in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5.3, logout

I spent 2 hours trying to logout users automatically but I cannot force users to logout after 24 hours no matter what I do.

After a successful login I have a cookie that looks like this

```
Name: remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d

Content: eyJpdiI6IkE4aFU0RCtVNkhwK3VMbGJ0ZndVUFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidExYTG9tUUc5RkVQUkhjaU80a1wvdHFXcDk4eUxsaG5SRmxLVXp5c1JMdFJlYzFLZ3ZValBoQkhaY1hkKzFqcHIraDROZE5wU0s0K00wRDlMSVExMk50cUxNK2xzMzgrdmx4VW1hZ1paWVpJPSIsIm1hYyI6Ijc2NDZiYTI2MTU1NTA0YjZjMjA4ZmY1ZmU2MzdmZGFhYzdkMWU4NTRmNzEwYzIwZjRkN2E3ZDNlMDQyNWQ5N2QifQ%3D%3D

Created: Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 6:55:00 PM
Expires: Sunday, December 11, 2022 at 6:55:00 PM
```

my session.php file look like this

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
'lifetime' => 1,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

My env file looks like this

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=database
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

My php.ini looks like this

```
session.gc_maxlifetime=14
```

I tried to change 
`'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),` to file, cookie, redis nothing worked.

Why can I not logout users from all devices?

Comment: Removing the files in the session directory? Using the file driver, of course...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Inactivity time setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133830/laravel-inactivity-time-setting)

Comment: @amarnasan I can log users out by setting remember_token to NULL but I need to force them to logout every 24 hours.

Comment: What puzzles me is that cookie name "remember_web_...." Where does it come from?

Comment: I was thinking that this cookie name is laravel's feature. I haven't set such a cookie name.

Comment: May be following answer will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326256/laravel-kill-session-and-cookie-from-console-command/49332222#49332222

Comment: You should refer to this tutorial https://codezen.io/how-to-manage-logged-in-devices-in-laravel/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the time period for an idle session to expire in the `/app/config/session.php` file.

> 24Hrs = 1440 minutes

```
'lifetime' => 1440,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

**Alternatively, you can do this if the above method is not working for you,**

We are going to manually delete sessions folder and clear all remember_tokens in User table.

create a [new command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan)  `flush:session`.

in the command's handle method do:

```
use App\User;
use File;

public function handle()
{
    File::cleanDirectory(storage_path().'/framework/sessions');
    User::query()->update(['remember_token' => '']);
}
```

and then [schedule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling) this command to run every midnight

```
$schedule->command('flush:session')->daily();
```

**P.S** If you want an instant test of this, just run

```
php artisan flush:session
```

in the terminal and all your users should be logged out!

Comment: hi Sapnesh Naik. Thank for the reply. I set it to '1' just to see whether users are logging out or not. when I check the cookie it is always says expires in 2022. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Did your test pass? If yes then you can use this method without problems.

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't log the users out. I can log a user out by setting remember_token to NULL in my users table but I need to force them to logout every 24 hours. Tried this article out https://arjunphp.com/laravel5-inactivity-idle-session-logout/ didn't work either. I am getting RuntimeException in Request.php line 905:
Session store not set on request.

Comment: I am testing out another way, wait

Comment: testing now. Do I need to create a cron job from cpanel to run the command every midnight?

Comment: Check the task scheduling section in Laravel docs, you only need to run one command every minute in cron, `php artisan schedule:run`

Comment: your method worked for me. I also found this http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/session-timeout-for-logged-in-user it also works for me. Still not sure why lifetime didn't worked for me.

Comment: I need your expertise on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972020/how-to-send-html-elements-trough-json-using-php  this subject. Woud you please have a look if this is possible? Thank you.