# How to send HTML elements through JSON using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json, escaping

The following function

```
    try{
        $query =  $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE TourID = ? AND dTourDate = ? and Status NOT LIKE 'Cancelled'");
        $query->execute(array($tourId,$date));
        $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(count($result)<1)
            $this->error("'Booking' Not Found.",$this->errCode->sqlNotBooking);
        $this->success("Booking List Success.",(array) $result);
    }
```

returns me this:

```
 TotalPrice":"0.00","GuestName":"Bryan Pedrochi<\/span>","ContactNumber":"042214"...
```

The GuestName column in mysql looks like this

```
<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">Bryan Pedrochi</span>
```

I am not very good in programming and I am not sure how to do it but I believe I have to place backslash before the double quote in regarding to have a proper result like this

```
TotalPrice":"0.00","GuestName":"<style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);\">Bryan Pedrochi</span>","ContactNumber":"042214"...
```

So, I tried

```
$add= $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$string=serialize($add); 
$result=addslashes($string);
```

I tried

```
$this->success("Booking List Success.",(array) htmlentities($result));
```

but nothing seems to work. Is it possible to return HTML elements and backslashes in JSON results?

Comment: Why store html elements together with a name? If you need custom color, you can always store it in a separate column. Looks like very poor architecture design :(

Comment: Html elements send by WYSIWYG editor. I would like to see the colors etc in the results. I have an iphone app that lists the query results but if it is not plain text then it doesn't show the results after the aforementioned name.

Comment: In that case I would have chosen a different wysiwyg editor, to be honest. The best solution for you is to refactor your code to achieve better design. Unfortunately, it is against my good judgement to advice you on some workarounds, since your logic saving html with a name is harmful enough already.

Comment: So, are we not supposed to have html characters in JSON result?

Comment: You completely missed the point of my comments. Good luck.

Comment: As you can see on the link https://www.thorntech.com/2012/07/4-things-you-must-do-when-putting-html-in-json/ there are html elements in json result. I believe I just have to put backslash in front of it to able to display it in the mobile app. I am sorry I couldn't understand your point. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to strip the html tags.

```
try{
    $query =  $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE TourID = ? AND dTourDate = ? and Status NOT LIKE 'Cancelled'");
    $query->execute(array($tourId,$date));
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $resultStrip = json_decode(strip_tags(json_encode($result)), true);
    if(count($resultStrip )<1)
        $this->error("'Booking' Not Found.",$this->errCode->sqlNotBooking);
    $this->success("Booking List Success.",(array) $resultStrip);
}
```

hope it helps.