# Laravel - kill session and cookie from console command?

Tags: laravel

Is there any way, within a Laravel console command, to clear the session and/or the remember me cookie?

The console command is designed to deactivate users, and so if a user is deactivated while they are logged in, I want them to automatically be logged out.

But I'm not sure this is possible.  Ideas?

Comment: Why you need it in console command ? The cookies are stored in the user browser. Like @Sergio Reis answer A middleware is enough to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that why don't you try this approach? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/middleware-where-user-status-is-not-active?page=1

basicly, have a middleware that checks if the current user is active, in case it is not, redirect him to login

Answer (score -1):

Following process may help you. You can create command of following process.

You need to delete session files from "sessions" folder.

Normally Laravel stores sessions in "storage\framework\sessions" folder.

If you delete all files from session folder , all active user will automatically logged out.

You can find out session file using id from session folder and delete those files who are deactivated.

==========================================================

I had worked to prepare the solution

update config/filesystems.php file as following.

```
 'disks' => [
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],
        'adminfile' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('framework'),
        ],
```

Then you can use following code to delete the session file for particular user.

In my case , session element stored in "login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d" , so I have used "***if(preg_match('/login_web_(.*)/i',$key))***" in below code

```
    $files = Storage::disk('adminfile')->allFiles("sessions");
    $users = user::where('is_deactivate',true);
    foreach($users as $user){ 
    foreach($files as $file){ 
      if($file!="sessions/.gitignore" and          Storage::disk('adminfile')->exists($file)){
        $contents = unserialize(Storage::disk('adminfile')->get($file));
        foreach($contents as $key=>$value){
         if(!is_array($value) and !is_object($value)){
           if(preg_match('/login\_web\_(.*)/i',$key))
            {
             if($value==$user->id){
                Storage::disk('adminfile')->delete($file); 
             }
            }
          }
        }  
     }
    }
}
```